# How to show tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning php & mysql.I am trying to show my table and I have followed the exact same codes written in the book that I'm using:

```
<?php

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")
  or die("<p>Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error()."</p>");
  echo "<p>Connected to MySQL!</p>";
  $con = mysqli_select_db($con,"register")
 or die("<p>Error selecting the database register:  ".mysqli_error()." </p>");
  echo "<p>Connected to MySQL, using database register.</p>";
  $result = mysqli_query("SHOW TABLES;");
?>
```

but I keep getting this error:

> "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\SCRIPT\connect.php on line 12"

Comment: You have to pass the $con as a second param to mysqli_query if memory serves me well

Comment: Try this, $result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");

Comment: You should start with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @Ayno $result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");

Answer (score 0):

Is the most simple SQL statement for doing that. You can also take a look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES if you want to have more details or do some filtering or such.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'your_database';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) requires two parameters. You only provide one. When you see an error message like this the first thing you need to do is go to the manual. If you did you would see you must provide your MySQLi link as the first parameter:

`$result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");`

I hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have error at line

```
$result = mysqli_query("SHOW TABLES;");
```

**1.) pass **$con** as parameter.

**LIKE**:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES");
```

**2.) dont use same variable name for**

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")
 or die("<p>Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error()."</p>");
 echo "<p>Connected to MySQL!</p>";
```

**and**

```
$con = mysqli_select_db($con,"register")
 or die("<p>Error selecting the database register:  ".mysqli_error()." </p>");
 echo "<p>Connected to MySQL, using database register.</p>";
```

Comment: You can write this in comment. Removing the "";**. Still its not an issue if we write ; in statement

Comment: you are using same variable $con

Comment: check this line from question `$con = mysqli_select_db($con,"register")` he is assigning the value to `$con`. So it throws error saying parameter first must be object not an boolean value.

Comment: ya he is passing only one parameter to mysqli_query() function also

Comment: Don't downvote if you are not sure about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "register") or die("<p>Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error()."</p>");

echo "<p>Connected to MySQL, using database register.</p>";

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW TABLES");
```

UPDATED:

```
$result = mysql_query($con, "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='register'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['TABLE_NAME'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but I seems like it worked. I didn't show any error, only this result that I would get if I hadn't put the show tables line "Connected to MySQL!

Connected to MySQL, using database register."

Comment: what you want to is to show all the tables in your database?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the purpose of this statement.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using mysqli you must follow mysqli syntax for select query

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")
or die("<p>Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error()."</p>");
echo "<p>Connected to MySQL!</p>";
```

// you are assigning value back to con object

```
 mysqli_select_db($con,"register")
 or die("<p>Error selecting the database register:  ".mysqli_error()."   </p>");
 echo "<p>Connected to MySQL, using database register.</p>";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES;");
?>
```

Comment: yes I did that. I mean I added the variable $con as a parameter but I was still getting an error. This error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in"

Comment: Anyo I have updated th answer please have a look. You are assigning `$con` an value with boolean